# C# WebKit Dot Net navigate with post data

Tags: c#

for one of my project i need a webbrowser in a c# programm. At first i tryed to use the default webbrowser but this use the IE8 and this dont run for me. After this i implemenent the WebkitDotNet ([Link](http://webkitdotnet.sourceforge.net/)). The implementation was very easy and all functions run, but now i need a navigate call with post data in the request. i searched all but i dont find a anwser. I hope you can help me.
this is the normal navigate function `webKitBrowser1.Navigate("http://test.seite");` but this function dont have a parameter to send post data

Comment: Try `CefSharp`: https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp

Comment: i dont want to change the plugin again. first was ghecko now the webkit

Comment: There is something fishy here. Why not post through the site itself? Or post with a simple `HttpClient`? Navigation is normally done through `httpget`.